# Begriff für Schwiegereltern aus der Sicht der eigenen Eltern

Tags: single-word-request

Die Eltern meiner Freundin sind meine Schwiegereltern. Was ist die Bezeichnung aus der Sicht meiner Eltern?

Zum Beispiel: wenn sich meine Eltern sich mit den Nachbarn unterhalten:

> Wir kennen unsere (...) noch nicht.

Comment: Die Briten sagen dazu manchmal *co-mother-in-law* bzw. *co-father-in-law*, das ist aber nicht sehr verbreitet (Ist das jetzt das englische Wort mit den meisten Bindestrichen?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Gegenschwieger, Gegenschwäher

Ersteres kennt der Duden als *landschaftlich* (und das auch nur in der "dicken" zehnbändigen Gesamtausgabe), zweiteres gar nicht. Grimm's Wörterbuch kennt beide.

Ich kenne aus dem Raum Stuttgart nur ersteres (ist aber jetzt nicht so, dass ich das Wort noch sehr häufig hören würde...). Wo der Begriff sonst noch verbreitet ist: keine Ahnung - wäre vielleicht eine kleine Umfrage wert...

Ansonsten dürfte

> Die Eltern unsrer Schwiegertochter/unsres Schwiegersohns

der derzeit gebräuchlichste Ausdruck sein.

Answer (score 2):

Eigentlich kenne ich **Schwippschwager** in Übereinstimmung mit dem Duden als Schwager des Ehepartners, also:

```
 +----Schwager/Schwägerin------+
 |                             |
Ich --- Meine Frau  ---  ihre Schwester --- deren Mann
 |          |                                   |  |
 |          +---------- Schwager/Schwägerin ----+  |
 |                                                 |
 +----- Schwippschwager ---------------------------+
```

Aber [Wikipedia behauptet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwippschwager):

> Gelegentlich werden auch Gegenschwiegereltern (Eltern des Schwiegerkindes) und Stiefgeschwister als Schwippschwäger bezeichnet.

Comment: Wir sagen in unserer Familie (Norddeutschland) schon seit ca 25 Jahren "Schwippschwiegereltern", aber ich kann nicht sagen, wo das mal hergekommen ist. Wäre möglich, dass sich das einfach mal jemand spontan ausgedacht hat durch Erweiterung von "Schwiegereltern" mit dem "Schwipp-" vom Schwippschwager. "Gegen-" klingt mir jedenfalls zu sehr nach Scheidungsanwalt.

Answer (score 0):

Mein Schwiegervater nannte meine Eltern die *Con-Eltern*. Leider weiß ich nicht, ob das Wort aus dem rheinischen Sprachraum kam oder seine persönliche Schöpfung war (die Vorsilbe "Con" könnte auf seiner besonderen Liebe zur lateinischen Sprache beruhen).

Answer (score -1):

Ich bin für Mitschwieger/Mitschwiegerin bzw Mitschwägerin - ähnlich der englischen Bezeichnung co-mother-in-law bzw. co-father-in-law.

Comment: Hallo Otto und Herzlich willkommen hier bei german.stackexchange! Wir versuchen hier, die deutsche Sprache zu beschreiben, aber nicht, Meinungsfragen über die Deutsche Sprache zu entscheiden. Deine Antwort klingt ein bisschen so, als wäre das deine persönliche Meinung. Ist das so? Falls nein, hast du Belege, dass dieser Ausdruck verwendet wird?